# How to referenced frames in H264/265 decoding with AVFrame (Libav)

Tags: h.264, libav, hevc

I am working on a project using LibAV as decoder for H264 and H265 videos. I took a decoder sample from Roxlu (http://roxlu.com/2014/039/decoding-h264-and-yuv420p-playback) as my initial point and tried to understand how things work. In my particular case, while decoding each frame, I also need to know if a frame is a reference frame referred to by other frames and need to know the list of frames a B or P frame is referring to. Do you guys have any idea how I can extract such information? I don't seem to find this information from the LibAV API (C++).

Thank you very much.